# Weird thing happening when adding UIViews to a ScrollView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ios4

I have a problem when adding UIViews to my scrollview:

```
NSArray *views = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:view1, view2, view3,nil];
    for (int i = 0; i < views.count; i++) {
        CGRect frame;
        frame.origin.x = self.scrollView.frame.size.width * i;
        frame.origin.y = 0;
        frame.size = self.scrollView.frame.size;



        [self.scrollView addSubview:[views objectAtIndex:i]];
    }


    self.pageControl.numberOfPages = views.count;
    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.scrollView.frame.size.width * views.count, self.scrollView.frame.size.height);
```

That's the code I'm using. The problem is that the ScrollView has the three pages, and all, but just the first page actually contains a view, which is the last one in the array. Why is this happening? I also tried:

```
for (UIView *view in views) {
    [self.scrollView addSubview:view];
}
```

With the same result. What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the position of the views you add:

```
[views objectAtIndex:i].frame = frame;
```

You are currently not changing the view's position anywhere, so all of them are probably at (0|0).

Comment: Haha, I didn't know that! I've never seen this before.

Answer (score 0):

You're initializing frame in your loop but omit to do anything with it. You need to replace each view's frame to use it.